# Information required in building DIY HHO production device

Tags: modulation, component-selection

I am going to try producing HHO (creating hydrogen and oxygen) and have been told that a "100 Amp 12 volt pulsed wave modulator" will increase the HHO production. I believe they mean pulse width modulation. I have no idea where to start. Could anyone advise me in building this. I am familiar with arduino and PWM, but no idea how to step it up to this voltage and amperage?

Comment: Some prior reading may help formulate a more structured and well-researched question, thus eliciting better quality of answers. Also, links to where the *pulsed wave modulator* is mentioned, may provide useful insight.

Comment: PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) may be what you mean? But perhaps the root issue is that you're building a device which sounds a lot like the snake-oil HHO generators for your car, which are complete junk and have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Ah yes. I understand PWM. It could be.

Comment: If you downvote please explain why

Comment: He did.  Read the first comment.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - there are 3 downvotes

Comment: @MarkW People will often not comment if they have the same reason, voting to close of a number different kinds also apply a downvote from the community user, which means the downvote is not always from a user, at least they did not intentionally. It seems you received your answer though.

Comment: I think it's a shame to close questions like this. The question was completely clear, there was potential education here and a discussion MAY have helped rescue a few people from the Dark Side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term "Pulsed Wave Modulator" was used for the PWM3G Hydrogen/Oxygen electrolysis unit produced by Bob Boyce of Hydrogen garage fame. Circuitry, instructions, guidance to principle of operation and more is said by the site to be available by following various links. Some were dead.

[Hydrogen Garage PWM3G page here](http://www.hydrogengarage.com/pwm3g/)

Home page here: http://www.hydrogengarage.com/

**He says** that his devices break several of the laws of Physics, that they do not follow Faradys's 1875 rules of electrolysis and that there are two type of Hydrogen.

**HE says** that EE types will say this is all rubbish, will not work etc.
 He's right.
 It's about the only thing he is right on.

### HHO is a no go ...

He is a con man,
this is a con,
the system is rubbish,
you can not get more energy out of the system than what you put in to split the water in the first place.

He does not understand the basic principles of the systems that he is working with or actively chooses to ignore them.
And, no, I was NOT the man from down under who he spoke to. I'd have been more polite :-).

As a fuel additive or partial fuel feed to a motor it MAY be that you can improve overall combustion efficiency and get improved mpg. But, you probably won't.  You CAN get improved performance by spraying water into the air/fuel inlet of an internal combustion engine. This was used on some WW2 aircraft (Hurricane was one AFAIK) and is still used commercially today AFAIK. *BUT* the principle of operation is unrelated to the claimed methods by which HHO is said to work. Water injection reduces "pinking" or detonation and allows higher compression ratios to be used. HHO is just bunkum.

You cannot break the laws of Physics.
 You CAN discover new "laws"  and
you can find that old laws were not quite correctly described.
 But the HHO area is very old well plowed and very infertile ground and very much the happy hunting ground of conmen, crackpots and hopeful marks waving handfuls of money at the dubious claimants.

But, if HHO takes your fancy as something fun and useful to pursue, go for it. But, try to remember what you read here before you spend too too much of your money or use up too much of your life on it.

A 12V 100 A system can at very very best make a system which has an energy output of 1200 Watts using of hydrogen as fuel. Burning it for heat is probably the most efficient method you'll get. The heat made may be inside an IC engine.

You can get H2 using biological systems that break down Methane or other feed stock - BUT the energy in such systems comes from somewhere - usually sunlight.

Comment: Normally I resist, but the fake science scandals out there get my goat, the videos online for this subject are almost as great as those claiming they recreated a great way to make free power and always have their circuit plugged into the wall. Your post was fun, thanks for doing the research, at least you get some rep for it.